# Testing viewsets with UploadedFile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest

I'm trying to test a particular viewset view which takes `formData` which contains  a `csv` file. My test looks like this:

```
    @staticmethod
    def _create_file(rows: List[List[Any]], content_type: str = 'text/csv') -> UploadedFile:
        f = StringIO()
        csv.writer(f).writerows(rows)
        return UploadedFile(file=f.read(), name='test.csv', content_type=content_type)

    def test_upload_valid(self):
        """ Asserts that the upload view works correctly with valid information. """
        response = self.client.post(reverse('core_api:upload-upload'), {
            'file_type': self.file_type,
            'file': self._create_file([['Test', 'Test', 'Test', 'Test'], [1, 'Test', 'tokyo', 2]])
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.content['process_status'], DemoConsumerDataParser.SUCCESS_STATUS)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.content['errors']), 0)
```

However this fails here:

```
'file': self._create_file([self.header, self.acceptable_row])
```

With the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How can I modify the post so it correctly sends this file?

Comment: I think the error comes from passing `f.read()` as the `file` arg to `UploadedFile`, which is expecting a file object instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've gotten around this by using `SimpleUploadedFile`, but I'm not sure why this works:

```
    @staticmethod
    def _create_file(rows: List[List[Any]]) -> SimpleUploadedFile:
        f = StringIO()
        csv.writer(f).writerows(rows)
        file = SimpleUploadedFile('test.csv', f.getvalue().encode(), content_type='text/csv')
        f.close()
        return file
```